# Looping C++ different output

Tags: c++, loops

how to create output like:

```
1
1122
111222333
1111222233334444
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a,b,c,d,n;
  cout<<"Masukkan akhir perulangan = ";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<"\nMenggunakan For\n";
    for(a=1; a<=n; a++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=a;c++)
        {
            for(b=1;b<=a;b++)
            {
                cout<<" "<<b;
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
  return 0;
}'
```

but my output is

```
1
1212
123123123
1234123412341234
```

Comment: Did you perchance mean to print c instead of b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should output `c` in the inner loop instead of `b`:

```
for(a=1; a<=n; a++)
{
    for(c=1;c<=a;c++)
    {
        for(b=1;b<=a;b++)
        {
            cout<<" "<<c;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```